# Leak in BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, leakcanary

Here is link to project that shows leak: https://github.com/Anton111111/BottomSheetLeak

If you click on show btn bottom sheet dialog will openned. And when you close bottom sheet leakcanary will show leak:

```
  ┬───
    │ GC Root: System class
    │
    ...
    ├─ com.example.anton111111.MainFragment instance
    │    Leaking: NO (Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
    │    ↓ MainFragment.bottomSheet
    │                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
    ├─ com.example.anton111111.MyBottomSheetDialog instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Retaining 115,8 kB in 1870 objects
    │    mContext instance of android.view.ContextThemeWrapper, wrapping activity com.example.anton111111.MainActivity with
    │    mDestroyed = false
    │    Dialog#mDecor is null
    │    ↓ Dialog.mWindow
    │             ~~~~~~~
    ├─ com.android.internal.policy.MiuiPhoneWindow instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Retaining 15,5 kB in 293 objects
    │    mContext instance of android.view.ContextThemeWrapper, wrapping activity com.example.anton111111.MainActivity with
    │    mDestroyed = false
    │    Window#mDestroyed is false
    │    ↓ PhoneWindow.mDecor
    │                  ~~~~~~
    ╰→ com.android.internal.policy.DecorView instance
    ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.android.internal.policy.DecorView received
    ​     View#onDetachedFromWindow() callback)
    ​     Retaining 2,7 kB in 48 objects
    ​     key = 6926a1af-7a43-4047-9a76-91a099507a62
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 12581
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 7575
    ​     View not part of a window view hierarchy
    ​     View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    ​     View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    ​     mContext instance of android.view.ContextThemeWrapper, wrapping activity com.example.anton111111.MainActivity
    ​     with mDestroyed = false
   
I Skipped log. Here is full leakcanary output: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Anton111111/BottomSheetLeak/master/leakcanary.log

Can i fix it?
```

Answer (score 0):

you are holding a reference to your `BottomSheetDialog` in the fragment that's why it's leaking. after dismissing, the reference prevents the Garbage collector to clean it. you should use a static method(companion object) to create the dialog and inflate the layout in `onCreateView` of the dialog.
see this [blog post](https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/android-bottom-sheet-5b64ddb3c02d) for more information.

Comment: i think you are wrong. On blog post described BottomSheetDialogFragment, but i use BottomSheetDialog. And i want reuse bottomSheetDialog to not create it again on each open.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference, when you call `dismiss()` the object needs to be cleared, but you are holding a reference to it so it leaks.in general, holding a reference to an object that has a smaller lifecycle results in a memory leak. if you look at leakcanary logs it complains the view object in the memory is detached(because you called dismiss) so it should not be in the memory, that's how it knows there is a leak

Comment: also when it's destroyed it can not be reused